# DefaultFilterChainValidator hangs in JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-security, spring-test

So, basically, I have a Spring app with some tests written for it. I use Gradle as a build tool.

On my local machine, when I run `./gradlew test`, tests run normally.
But if I run `./gradlew --info test` on the server, it hangs here:

```
00:17:56.962 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     [INFO ] 2017-06-04 00:17:56.957 [Test worker] DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/static/favicon.png'], []
00:17:56.963 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     
00:17:57.788 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     [INFO ] 2017-06-04 00:17:57.785 [Test worker] DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2f31c01c, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@8037423, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@786b4abb, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@5918a556, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7d37adb3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@6758fc2, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@20285a59, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@60cb2224, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter@2e211564, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1e4a09cc, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@12b71ea9, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2b469730, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1b0e8045]
00:17:57.792 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     
00:17:57.859 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     [INFO ] 2017-06-04 00:17:57.854 [Test worker] DefaultFilterChainValidator - Checking whether login URL '/login' is accessible with your configuration
```

So this is the last output I see. Not really sure what could possibly cause this. I tried to run this with strace, here's the full output just till the point where it hangs: [strace.log](https://gist.github.com/boggad/e57fb4023d2e9494185594414016c4f8)

I would really appreciate any help in investigation of this weird problem.

Here's [build.gradle](https://gist.github.com/boggad/78a6fe75924a9d8efe41458dc71bcc8f)
Here's [Spring Security configuration](https://gist.github.com/boggad/6907385c18236a948831c7b03cf3469f)

**Local machine:**

```
$ uname -srv
Linux 4.4.0-78-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 27 15:29:09 UTC 2017
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
$ ./gradlew --version | grep Gradle
Gradle 2.12
```

**Server:**

```
$ uname -srv
Linux 3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 25 17:04:51 UTC 2017
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b12, mixed mode)
$ ./gradlew --version | grep Gradle
Gradle 2.12
```